# Adding POST parameters after form submit

Tags: javascript, php, forms, post, submit

I have this form:

```
<form name="form" action="course_submit.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
...
</form>
```

And I'd like to add a few json arrays to POST in validateForm() after validation, so that when validateForm() returns true, the updated POST will be sent to course_submit.php. What's the best wya to go about this? Thanks!

Comment: show your validateForm() function

Comment: validateForm() is just checking some of the inputs to make sure they're sensible. The idea is after that, if all is well, I add a few new things to POST before shipping it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have `<input type="hidden" ...>` elements inside the form.

Assign the values to those elements.

Comment: Can I do that in the onsubmit() for the form, and have that data added to POST? I wouldn't have guessed it to be so easy.

Comment: Your question specifically asked about achieving this effect at that time, so yes.

Comment: I appreciate your patience with me. I tested this out, having <input type="hidden" name="test" value=""> in the form, and then running document.getElementsByName("test").value = "HELLO"; in the onsubmit() function, but I don't see it in post. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return